# React Native view display distorted pixels on iPhone Plus

Tags: iphone, react-native

React Native view display distorted pixels on iPhone Plus version while the same view display very elegantly on iPhone 5,6, or 7 version. Views sometime look more terrible then the image below on plus version of iPhone.
[image]
code is as follows,

```
<View style={[styles.headerRow, { paddingHorizontal: 5 }]} >
   <View style={{ flex: 3, borderColor: theme.color.gray.light, borderRightWidth: .5, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={[skin.text.smaller, skin.text.bold, { textAlign: 'center', padding: 8 }]}>{'TITLE'}</Text>
    </View>
   <View style={{ flex: 2, alignItems: 'center', borderColor: theme.color.gray.light, borderRightWidth: .5, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={[skin.text.smaller, skin.text.bold, { textAlign: 'center', padding: 8 }]}>{'BUCKIT'}</Text>
   </View>
   <View style={{ flex: 2.8, alignItems: 'center' }}>
         <Text style={[skin.text.smaller, skin.text.bold, { textAlign: 'center', padding: 8 }]}>{'YOUR AVERAGE'}</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

Using screen width to divid column instead of flex also does not helps.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

I found a solution, iOS does not prefer setting borderWidth less then 1 and thus you can either use 1 or greater value or react-native provide StylesSheet variable called hairlineWidth which has default value set to 0.3. You may change the value by setting StyleSheet.hairlineWidth = 0.5 in the constructor of the component.

```
<View style={{borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth}}> ... </View>
```